# Reading all files in a directory including its sub directories

Tags: java, file, recursion

This is how I set the path:

```
    dPath = dPath.replace("\\", "/");

    String iLen;
    String FileName;

    File iFolder = new File(dPath);
    File[] listOfFiles = iFolder.listFiles();
```

When searching:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
    {
        if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
        {
            FileName = listOfFiles[i].getName();

            for(String s : iEndsWith)
            {
                if(FileName.toLowerCase().endsWith(s))
                {
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy h:mm aaa");
                    iLen = ReadableBytes(listOfFiles[i].length());

                    Object rowData[] = { FileName, listOfFiles[i].getAbsoluteFile(), sdf.format(listOfFiles[i].lastModified()), iLen };
                    iTableModel.addRow(rowData);

                    iTotalFiles ++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

That will only look for files in the given directory path, but not it's sub directories. How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on Java 7, you can use `FileVisitor`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

If not, just use a simple recursive version of your function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DirectoryWalker](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/DirectoryWalker.html) from Apache Commons to walk through a directory hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Pass folder as Initial File which is to be searched

```
File foldr = new File("c:/javaFolder");

public void addFilesToList(File folder) {
        File[] listofFiles = folder.listFiles();
        if (listofFiles != null) {
            for (File file : listofFiles) {
                if (file.isFile()) {


                } else
                    addFilesToList(file);

            }
        }
    }
```